# npm not found in Docker container (but only when executed via child_process)

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, npm, child-process

I am trying to execute some commands with npm in a docker container. The Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM top20/node:8-alpine

COPY . .
EXPOSE 4201 80
...
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

During testing, i also tried other node-images (like `FROM node:lts-alpine`)

The CMD itself or any other RUN command within that Dockerfile will sucessfully be executed. At the end, the `npm start`opens a JavaScript-file containing the following command executed by [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html):

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;

...

exec("npm run some_script", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    ...
});
```

I get the error:

> /bin/sh: npm: not found

Testing other node-images, i also get sometimes:

> /usr/bin/env: 'node': No such file or directory

The code is working outside Docker environments.
The question of course is, how to get this running, and why things are happening in that way?

Comment: Did you check if npm was added to path in those containers?

Comment: yes. I also inserted the running container doing a sucessful npm -v

Comment: I vaguely remember that you might need to give your node script +x permission even though it's not a bash script. worth a try